# Adding new autofill cell and returning cell value to userform VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have been searching for a solution for hours, Can anyone help me?

I have a cmd button to open a user form and create a new entry in a 'master enquiry log' worksheet. I would like the cmd button to autofill the next number to the master log in column 'A' and then return that number to the user form.

I think there may need to be a user form initialization sub added but im not sure what to enter.

Any help will be much appreciated

```
    Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Master Enq. Log")
'find first empty row in database
iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1


'copy the data to the database
'use protect and unprotect lines,
'     with your password
'     if worksheet is protected
With ws
'  .Unprotect Password:="password"


  .Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.txtCustName.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.txtCustAddr.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Date
  .Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Me.cboProjEng.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 6).Value = Me.cboDrawer.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 11).Value = Me.cboSalesPers.Value
'  .Protect Password:="password"
End With

'clear the data
Me.txtCustName.Value = ""
Me.txtCustAddr.Value = ""
Me.cboProjEng.Value = "Select"
Me.cboDrawer.Value = "Select"
Me.cboSalesPers.Value = "Select"
Me.txtCustName.SetFocus

End Sub
```

Comment: You will need to populate the userform in the userform initialize event. You could probably get the max number in the range("A:A") and populate the form that way.

Comment: iRow  =  ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1